# How does one associate SSH keys with a Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I know how to [create a Google Compute Engine instance](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/tutorials/gcp/gce-webserver/) using pulumi, but how does one associate an SSH key with it at creation time?

Answer (score 4):

When creating the instance, you need to set the following metadata pair:

```
metadata: {
  "enable-oslogin": "false",
  "ssh-keys": username + ":" + sshPublicKey
}
```

To add multiple SSH keys, separate them with `\n`.

Enabling OS Login causes metadata-based SSH keys to get disabled: https://serverfault.com/a/1014949/15584

Further reading:

- https://www.pulumi.com/docs/tutorials/gcp/gce-webserver/
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only